# Unit Testing AntD Modal with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, antd

I'm trying to Unit test AntD modal in React using Jest and Enezym and it gives me following errors:

[image]

and another one

[image]

this as well:
   Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {destroy, update}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

and here's the modal I've created

```
import propTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Modal } from 'antd';

const SuccessModal = props => {
const { title, content } = props;
return Modal.success({
title,
content,
});
   };

SuccessModal.propTypes = {
title: propTypes.string.isRequired,
content: propTypes.string.isRequired,
  };
  export default SuccessModal;
```

and here are my unit tests

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import SuccessModal from './index';

describe('SuccessModal', () => {
  it('should render the component correctly in ', () => {
    shallow(<SuccessModal title="time to succeed" content="sucess content        success content" />);
  });
  it('check the props values', () => {
    const props = {
      title: 'this is a success title',
      content: 'sucess content sucess content',
    };

    const renderedComponent = shallow(<SuccessModal {...props} />);
    expect(renderedComponent.prop('title')).toBe('this is a success title');
    expect(renderedComponent.prop('content')).toBe('sucess content sucess content');
  });
});
```

I've also tried this way

```
  expect(

        (      
    <SuccessModal title="this is a success title" content="sucess content sucess content" />
  ).exists(),
).toEqual(true);
expect((   <SuccessModal title="this is a success title" content="sucess content sucess content" />).text()).toContain('this is a success title');
```

any help highly appreciated and if more clarification is needed let me know in the comment

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was asked almost 2 years ago, then I suppose the antd 3.x is used

Modal.success returns an object {destroy, update} hence the corresponding error:
"Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {destroy, update})..."

Here you need to use either a declarative approach:

```
const SuccessModal = props => {
    const {title, content} = props;
    return (
        <Modal title={title}> 
            {content}
        </Modal>
    );
};
```

And then test how you wanted.

Or call SuccessModal like a function.

```
SuccessModal(props);
```

When called as a function, а modal is created as a separate `div` inside the `body` tag. Therefore, to check the correctness of the call, you must check the DOM

```
expect(document.documentElement.outerHTML).toContain(props.title);
```